# Why add a abstract method to __init__ method of abstract class as an attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class

I am reading a book about python design patterns.
I feel a little puzzled When I see the code about 'factory' pattern.

```
class Profile(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sections = []
        **self.create_profile()**

    @abstractmethod
    def **create_profile**(self):
        pass

    def get_section(self):
        return self.sections
```

The method **create_profile** is a abstract method and it was add into **init** method.
Please let me clear the reason that why do that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: so if a derived class is built the parent init calls the specific create_profile if exists. And since the parent method is abstract it _has_ to be redefined in the child class

Comment: An abstract class just means that it has at least one unimplemented method left for its sub-class to implement before the sub-class can be instantiated. An implemented method such as `__init__` can call an abstract method as part of the logics, but still until the abstract method is implemented by a sub-class the `__init__` method can't run either because the base class can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It means when you write a subclass to inherit `Profile`, you must override the `abstract method`.

> A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods are overridden.

#### example code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Profile(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sections = []
        self.create_profile()

    @abstractmethod
    def create_profile(self):
        pass

    def get_section(self):
        return self.sections
    
class SubProfile(Profile):
    def __init__(self):
       self.create_profile()

    def create_profile(self):
        self.sections = [1,2,3]

class AnotherSubProfile(Profile):
    def __init__(self):
       self.create_profile()

    def create_profile(self):
        self.sections = [4,5,6]

class NoCreateSubProfile(Profile):
    def __init__(self):
       self.sections = [7,8,9]
    
sub = SubProfile()
print(sub.get_section())
sub = AnotherSubProfile()
print(sub.get_section())
sub = NoCreateSubProfile()
print(sub.get_section())
```

#### result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class NoCreateSubProfile with abstract method create_profile
```

Edit: about why it was add into init method, I think it is just a simple example, so the book writer put the abstract method into init method so that you can call it when you create a object of the subclass to `Profile` without any extra actions that need to do.

- In other <del>fancy</del> words, `create_profile` in `init` may indicate `Profile` must be created first when the instance of `Profile` are created.
- `create_profile` not in `init` example:(basic the same to former one)

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Profile(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sections = []
        # self.create_profile()

    @abstractmethod
    def create_profile(self):
        pass

    def get_section(self):
        return self.sections
    
class SubProfile(Profile):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_profile(self):
        self.sections = [1,2,3]
    
sub = SubProfile()
sub.create_profile()
print(sub.get_section())
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, I known it that the subclass must override the abstract method.
But I think no need add the abstract method into __init__ method on `Profile` class

Comment: @barry if you are happy with this answer, can you accept it as the solution?

Comment: Maybe there are some benefit I don't know that add the `create_profile` method into `__init__` method of `Profile` class

Comment: @barry It is just a simple example, so the book writer put the abstract method into init method so that you can call it when you create a object of the subclass to `Profile` without any extra actions that need to do.

Comment: What will happen If I don't add it to `__init__` method? I think the subclass inherit the `Profile` class that the subclass can call the method of parent class, no need add into `__init__` method.

Comment: ah.. @leaf_yakitori I know it. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @barry basically nothing happen, I have already edit it in my answer.

Comment: The `create_profile` method as a attribute of interface, the method will be auto called when to create a object from the subclass .

Comment: @barry would you mind accept my answer or if you have further question about it?

Comment: I accept and click the “√” icon. 
Thanks @leaf_yakitori, this is my first request in this.